# How to apply colors to console.log when using multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I'm trying to style the output of my `console.log()` to make my application errors stand out.

So far this works:

```
console.log('%cHello World', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
```

But this doesn't:

```
var text = "Hello World";
var style = "background: #222; color: #bada55";
console.log('%c', text, style);
```

It just returns `background: #222; color: #bada55`. What am I missing?

Comment: try this `console.log('%c '+ text, style);`

Comment: `console.log('%c%s', style, text);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add `text` in first argument after `%c` using template literals

```js
var text = "Hello World";
var style = "background: #222; color: #bada55";
console.log(`%c${text}`, style);
```

Without template strings it will be

```js
var text = "Hello World";
var style = "background: #222; color: #bada55";
console.log('%c' + text, style);
```

Answer (score 8):

When you need to log multiple arguments, you can use following approach:

```
const log = (...args) => {
  let messageConfig = '%c%s   ';

  args.forEach((argument) => {
    const type = typeof argument;
    switch (type) {
        case 'bigint':
        case 'number':
        case 'boolean':
            messageConfig += '%d   ';
            break;

        case 'string':
            messageConfig += '%s   ';
            break;

        case 'object':
        case 'undefined':
        default:
            messageConfig += '%o   ';
    }
  });

  console.log(messageConfig, 'color: orange', '[LOGGER]', ...args);
};

log('my message', 123, 'qwerty', { foo: 'bar' }, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

here is result:
[image]